# How to extract "executable" strings from a string containing valid python?

Tags: python

I'd like to parse a string such as:

```py
code_str = """
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b

foo(
    a=1,
    b=2
)
"""
```

To get a list of "executable" strings (multi-lined or not)

```py
code_snippets = extract_executable_strings(code_str)
assert code_snippets = [
    "def foo(a, b):\n\treturn a + b\n",
    "foo(\n\ta=1\n\tb=2\n)\n"
]
```

So that I can do such things as execute the snippets one by one, or produce an equivalent doctest string such as:

```py
"""
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     return a + b
>>>
>>> foo(
...     a=1,
...     b=2
... )
"""
```

Of course, the simple cases can be covered by regular expressions, but to cover all valid python it seems like I should tap into python's parser itself instead of rewriting (a bad) one myself.

Comment: You seem to be describing basic usage of [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse \*.py file with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789301/how-to-parse-py-file-with-python)

Comment: @wim, `ast` is probably involved here, yes, but I wouldn't say it's basic usage. Indeed, `ast.parse` does the parsing, and does provide me with a `_ast.Module` object that has a `.body` attribute that is a `[<_ast.FunctionDef...>, <_ast.Expr...>]`. So it knows. But how do I extract my original strings from there beats me.

Comment: @mkrieger1, no it doesn't answer my question. The question itself is relevant to mine, but no answer in there is directly useful to me.

Comment: Well there is `ast.unparse` for that, but why the parser roundtrip? Anything wrong with `code_str.split("\n\n")`?

Comment: @wim. Yes, `ast.unparse` is the missing piece of the puzzle. I didn't see it because new to 3.9. There is an equivalent pip `astunparse` to fill the gap. No to `code_str.split("\n\n")` though, which is easily broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the function that does the exact job described by the question.

```py
from ast import parse as ast_parse

try:
    # Try ast.unparse (3.9+)
    from ast import unparse as ast_unparse
except ImportError:
    try:
        from astunparse import unparse as ast_unparse
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        raise ModuleNotFoundError(
            "Can't find a ast unparse function -- you'll need python 3.9+ or (pip/conda) install astunparse")


def extract_executable_strings(code_str: str):
    """Extract code blocks from code_str

    >>> code_str = '''
    ... def foo(a, b):
    ...     return a + b
    ...
    ... foo(
    ...     a=1,
    ...     b=2
    ... )
    ... '''
    >>> blocks = list(extract_executable_strings(code_str))
    >>> len(blocks)
    2
    >>> print(blocks[0])
    def foo(a, b):
        return (a + b)
    >>> print(blocks[1])
    foo(a=1, b=2)

    """
    for ast_obj in ast_parse(code_str).body:
        yield ast_unparse(ast_obj).strip()
```