# JavaScript: Parse python class

Tags: javascript, python, parsing

I upload python file with a python class(react form).

myfile.py

```
class MyClass():
"""
a: string - parameter a
"""
```

Is there any way I can get an annotation or list parans from the file with class using javascript? (without regexp)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on not using **regex**, there are only one other way : parse the file using a python parser.

You can do it in pure Javascript. It may be possible for example with [`dt-python-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dt-python-parser) to *visitor* the nodes you are interested in, but I have not tested it.

Or you can use Python code. Either you call your own server or an online service (if such exists). If you have access to a Python interpreter, from there you could use the `ast` Python standard library to [parse py files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789301/11384184).

The overblown solution would be to embed a Python interpreter through WASM into your Javascript app, to parse the uploaded file.